# Searl effect generator simulation

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, quantum-spin, simulations

This is an scheme of SEG:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUUvhuQtba4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAMrTxMzrds

This mechanism change the electrons around the conversor. Would be really nice to see the electron flux.

Do electrons act as little magnetics, right? How can i do this simulation? They have charge and magnetic moments, spin, etc...

Answer (score 1):

To say I am skeptical would be an understatement. I briefly worked on this around 1997 and what I see here, although it matches his description of what he wanted, in no ways matches the effects he claimed for his "original" which exhibited massive positive feedback, ionization, extreme cooling and massive antigravity effects. The over-unity claims were just icing on the cake.

Comment: Many people don't believe in searl effect. I believe because his claims matches with teorical model that i made using superconductive effect. But how simulate it? This electrons flux. (Sorry if bad english)

Answer (score 0):

At least, SEG applies the magnetic mirror effect with multi layer of magnets. If someone has a good setup, the multilayer magnetic field produces good plasma confinement. Btw, very strong toroidal magnetic  field may produce thrust force, theoretically. 
It's worth to have simulation of such thing, so that one does not have to spend half million bucks on it.